# Google Sheets: Array formula from Google Forms with Index Match / LookUp

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, array-formulas, google-forms

first time poster here.

I am trying to import Google Form responses into a Google Sheet tracker. Given the Google Form inserts a new row for each response, I need to use Array formulas. However, I am having trouble adapting the following formulas to be arrays:

**1. Last non-blank cell in a range (subset of a row, based on an if statement**
Current attempt works on the first row, but does not create an array:

```
=arrayformula(INDEX('Inbound Request Forms'!F2:K2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(('Inbound Request Forms'!F2:K2<>0),0),0)))
```

**2. First non-blank cell in a range (subset of a row), based on an if statement**
Current attempt:

```
=arrayformula(if(E74="Product category change",ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/('Inbound Request Forms'!A2:2>0),'Inbound Request Forms'!A2:2)),""))
```

Here is an [example doc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gljTZqY8jJMDOWbFwk3IKaxisBmvc2-q/view?usp=sharing) I made, feel free to edit.

Thank you!

Comment: Would a custom formula using Apps Script be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Can you add a tab called 'desired output' with the results you'd like for the sample data.  That'd make it easier to track which columns to pull for which types of form answers.